# Optimizing MysQL query,

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have simple MySQL query which runs really slowly.

```
INSERT INTO People_by_County (City, County, State, score, Month_, person_id)
SELECT people.City, people.County, people.State, PPL_month.score, PPL_month.Month_, PPL_month.person_id
FROM PPL_month
INNER JOIN people ON PPL_month.person_id = people.person_id
```

Where is 700K rows in people table, and 2,9Mln rows in PPL_month table. The thing is that, before I ran similar query on different tables, and on 1 table there was 700K rows on another 400Mln and query was finished in 6h. And this one is running almost for 24h. Any ideas why it's so slow ? No other queries are running at the time, so no one is using up RAM.

Bellow you can see Explain of the query.

[image]

Comment: Is there an index on the `person_id` column in the `people` table?

Comment: Could you give information about the structure of the tables? Do you have indexes? Did you arealdy tried using the MySQL EXPLAIN function to understand what's up with the query?

Comment: post the structure, the indexes, and run it with an explain(just the select part) and post the result too

Comment: is that a migration query? if so, then I think you don't need to worry on that since you're going to call it once.

Comment: There are no indexes in both tables.

Comment: Possibly your tables are have no index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `INDEX`on `PERSON` table as well as `PPL_Month` table.Then try to Execute this query

```
SELECT people.City, people.County, people.State, PPL_month.score, PPL_month.Month_, PPL_month.person_id
FROM PPL_month
INNER JOIN people ON PPL_month.person_id = people.person_id
```

How much time it took for execution?Note down that timing and Note down Execution timing for same query without creating index on both table.
You will definitely get more timing.
So indirectly it indicates that Data you want to insert is more dependent on how fast it was fetched.
So once Fetching is fast obviously insertion is faster than previous one.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you. But could you help me understand the process. I thought that in order to index you must have only unique values, which I do have in People table, but not in PPL_month ( there are multiple same person_id). How does indexing work on this table ?  Does it ignore all other same values ?

Comment: @Extria If you don't have unique values for specific table then you can achieve uniqueness using combine two or more column,again it is totally depends on your execution plan.So it is advisable to always check your query execution using Explain and then only continue with creating index on combination of multiple column.
Syntex for same is
`create index idx on tablename (column1, column2);`.
For further clarification or discussion about same please check this: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql